# "Normalize" a 2D Vector in C++ using lambda

Tags: c++, vector, lambda, normalization

I am implementing a lambda to row normalize a 2D vector in C++. Consider the simple case of a 3x3 matrix.

```
1 0 1
0 1 0
0 1 1
```

My *normalization factor* is the sum of non-zero entries in the row. Each entry is then divided by this normalization factor. For instance, row 1 has 2 non-zero entries summing up 2. Therefore, I divide each entry by 2.  The row normalized vector is defined as follows:

```
1/2 0  1/2
0   1   0
0  1/2 1/2
```

The relevant normalization code is shown here(note MAX_SIZE = 3). There is a syntactical error in the lambda capture list.

```
for(int i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE ; i++)
{
   transform(matrix[i].begin(),matrix[i].end(),matrix.begin(), [matrix[i].begin()](int x){
                return distance(matrix[i].begin(),lower_bound(matrix[i].begin(),matrix[i].end(),x))});

}
```

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: May be you miss `matrix[i].end()` in capture list?

Comment: I am confused.  You want to normalize a vector, or you want to normalize a matrix (what does that even mean?), or you want to normalize the column vectors of a matrix, or what

Comment: @DietrichEpp: I wish to row normalize a vector.

Comment: It looks like you're normalizing the matrix rows using the L1 metric.  You might want to mention that, because normally, (1/2, 0, 1/2) is considered to have a magnitude of 0.707, not 1.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: I don't think I am using the L1 Metric. I just want to ensure that sum of the  non-zero elements of a row sum to 1.

Comment: What do you mean by *normalize*? How did you get the `2` in the denominator? What is *MWE*?

Comment: "Normalize" is a technical term with a specific meaning.  If you want to make the rows add up to 1, that's a fine goal, but I was a little confused about what you actually wanted because "normalize" means that you make the magnitude 1 by some metric.  The L1 metric is when you add the absolute value of each component.  Adding the values together without absolute value isn't a metric, so we wouldn't call it normalization.

Comment: I chose normalization for the lack of a better term, but I've updated the question description to explain the context with the help of an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lambda capture list in C++ can only specify the *names* of values to capture, and `matrix[i].begin()` is not a name, it is a temporary value.  You can either give it a name or you can make a variable for it in the enclosing scope.  Much of the surrounding code is missing, so I invented a working version of the code for you to dissect:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdio>

template<int N>
void normalize(double (&mat)[N][N]) {
    std::for_each(std::begin(mat), std::end(mat),
        [](double (&row)[N]) {
            double sum = std::accumulate(std::begin(row), std::end(row), 0.0);
            std::transform(std::begin(row), std::end(row), std::begin(row),
                [sum](double x) { return x / sum; });
        });
}

template<int N>
void print(const double (&mat)[N][N]) {
    std::for_each(std::begin(mat), std::end(mat),
        [](const double (&row)[N]) {
            std::for_each(std::begin(row), std::end(row),
                [](double x) { std::printf(" %3.1f", x); });
            std::putchar('\n');
        });
}

int main() {
    double mat[3][3] = {
        { 1, 0, 1 },
        { 0, 1, 0 },
        { 0, 1, 1 },
    };
    std::puts("Matrix:");
    print(mat);
    normalize(mat);
    std::puts("Normalized:");
    print(mat);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Matrix:
 1.0 0.0 1.0
 0.0 1.0 0.0
 0.0 1.0 1.0
Normalized:
 0.5 0.0 0.5
 0.0 1.0 0.0
 0.0 0.5 0.5
```

This code is a bit weird, as far as C++ code goes, because it uses lambdas for everything instead of loops (or mixing `for` loops with higher-order-functions).  But you can see that by having a variable for each row (named `row`) we can make it very easy to loop over that row instead of specifying `matrix[i]` everywhere.

The weird syntax for array parameters `double (&mat)[N][N]` is to avoid pointer decay, which allows us to use `begin()` and `end()` in the function body (which don't work if the parameters decay to pointers).